# Get ID token of a user using custom Admin REST API in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

In a system I'm developing now, I want to get an ID token of a user in my Keycloak server using admin REST API of Keycloak, without knowing the password of the user (i.e., using only the password of an admin user).

That is, I want to have an admin API like
`GET /{realm}/users/{id}/id-token`.

Is it possible to realize this?

(The document of Keycloak says it is possible to implement custom API endpoints (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_extensions_rest),
but I'm not sure if I can add my desired function.)

Comment: May not fit your use case, but you may want to check service account (client credentials flow) feature. You can give roles to service account (you need to enable it for client, and it must be of confidential type). Then on your backend, instead of impersonating user, you can retrieve service account's credentials using client id and client secret, and with these credentials (tokens), you can then perform required call. That way, it is service that is doing the data manipulation, not impersonated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a very dangerous feature (IDP admin can pretend to be any user from his IDP user pool). But you are still missing one input - client. Each client may generate different token.

I would say that you may need:

1.) Example access token feature (not ID token!)

Check `GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/evaluate-scopes/generate-example-access-token` endpoint

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html

2.) Impersonation feature

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#impersonation

3.) Implement it on your own in the Keycloak, so it will exactly fit your needs.